# How can I change the macOS target version to 12.0 for a PyInstaller-built app package on Apple M1 using an external build system?

Tags: pyinstaller, apple-m1

I am using PyInstaller as my external build system to package my app for submission to the Mac App Store. Since I am using an Apple M1 processor, I have built my app for arm architecture only, without including x86 (universal) support.

However, when using the transporter tool to submit the package, it complains that the macOS target version should be set to a minimum of 12.0.

The issue I'm facing is that all the modules in my app are built with a minimum target of 11.0, and I need to change it to 12.0 post-build. I'm looking for an easy way to modify the minimum macOS target version to 12.0 on macOS.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

can be set in info.plist with:

LSMinimumSystemVersion
12.00